# Creating a tablib Dataset using a URL that points to a .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tablib

I am trying to use the tablib library and create a Dataset from a .csv file. The following works:

```
import tablib
dataset = tablib.Dataset().load(open('data.csv').read())
```

However, in some cases, I'd like to load the .csv file from a URL.
Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
def get_ds(filename):
    return tablib.Dataset().load(open(filename).read())
```

You want

```
import os.path
import requests

def get_ds(src):
    if os.path.exists(src):
        txt = open(src).read()
    else:
        req = requests.get(src)
        req.raise_for_status()
        txt = req.text

    return tablib.Dataset().load(txt)
```